# circleci python -t flag when running tests does not work

Tags: circleci

I have this run step in my circle.yaml file with no checkout or working directory set:

```
 - run:      
      name: Running dataloader tests
      command: venv/bin/python3 -m unittest discover -t dataloader tests
```

The problem with this is that the working directory from the `-t` flag does not get set. I have `moduleNotFound` Errors when trying to find an `assertions` folder inside the `dataloader` class.

My tree:

```
├── dataloader
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── assertions
```

But this works:

```
version: 2
defaults: &defaults
  docker:
    - image: circleci/python:3.6
jobs:
  dataloader_tests:
    working_directory: ~/dsys-2uid/dataloader
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/dsys-2uid
      ...
      - run:
          name: Running dataloader tests
          command: venv/bin/python3 -m unittest discover -t ~/app/dataloader tests
```

Any idea as to what might be going on?

Why doesn't the first one work with just using the -t flag?

What does `working directory` and `checkout` with a path actually do? I don't even know why my solution works.

Answer (score 1):

The exact path to the tests folder from the top has to be specified for 'discovery' to work. For example:'python -m unittest discover src/main/python/tests'. That must be why its working in the second case.

Its most likely a bug with 'unittest discovery' where discovery works when you explicitly specify namespace package as a target for discovery.But it does not recurse into any namespace packages inside namespace_pkg. So when you simply run 'python3 -m unittest discover' it doesn't go under all namespace packages (basically folders) in cwd.

Some PRs are underway(for example:[issue35617](https://bugs.python.org/issue35617)) to fix this, but are yet to be released

Answer (score 0):

**checkout** = Special step used to check out source code to the configured path (defaults to the working_directory). The reason this is a special step is because it is more of a helper function designed to make checking out code easy for you. If you require doing git over HTTPS you should not use this step as it configures git to checkout over ssh.

**working_directory** = In which directory to run the steps. Default: ~/project (where project is a literal string, not the name of your specific project). Processes run during the job can use the $CIRCLE_WORKING_DIRECTORY environment variable to refer to this directory. Note: Paths written in your YAML configuration file will not be expanded; if your store_test_results.path is $CIRCLE_WORKING_DIRECTORY/tests, then CircleCI will attempt to store the test subdirectory of the directory literally named $CIRCLE_WORKING_DIRECTORY, dollar sign $ and all.